# Tkinter: 2 buttons next to each other resize in width with window. How to?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

The 2 buttons should take each of the half of the  window, one on the left, one on the right. The height is fixed all time. With `.grid()` nor `.place()` I can come to that result. The red bar is the color of the frame where the buttons are placed on. The buttons resize in width with the window, but keep their constant height.

How to?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red')
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="<<")
button2 = tk.Button(frame, text=">>")

button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx.
In the mean time I got this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red',height=30)
frame.pack(fill='both')

button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="<<")
button2 = tk.Button(frame, text=">>")

button1.place(relwidth=0.5, relx=0, relheight=1)
button2.place(relwidth=0.5, relx=0.5, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the buttons are the only widgets in the frame (ie: you are making a toolbar), I would use `pack`. `grid` will also work, but it requires one extra line of code.

### Using pack

Here's a version with `pack`. Notice that the frame is packed along the top and fills the window in the "x" direction. The buttons each are instructed to expand (ie: receive extra, unused space) and to fill the space allocated to them in the "x" direction.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red',height=30)
frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="<<")
button2 = tk.Button(frame, text=">>")

button1.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=True)
button2.pack(side="right", fill="x", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

### Using Grid

A version with `grid` is similar, but you must use `columnconfigure` to give a non-zero weight to the two columns:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red',height=30)
frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

button1 = tk.Button(frame, text="<<")
button2 = tk.Button(frame, text=">>")

button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")

frame.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see bg='red'

Comment: @toyotaSupra: it's in the line where `frame` is defined.